# Контрастная последовательность

Tags: python

Не могу решить задачу:

Будем называть контрастной последовательность со следующим свойством: если посчитать разности между соседними элементами, то у возникшей последовательности знаки соседних элементов будут разными.

Например, последовательность [2,6,3,10,5,6] является контрастной, поскольку знаки разностей сменяют друг друга: [4,−3,7,−5,1].

А вот последовательности [2,3,6,5,6] и [1,6,3,5,5] не являются таковыми

Поскольку в жизни такая последовательность встречается не слишком часто, поэтому вам нужно найти наибольшую контрастную подпоследовательность. Это значит, что вы можете удалять любые элементы (порядок оставшихся должен сохраниться). Хотя если вся последовательность является контрастной, то ничего удалять, конечно, не требуется.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот мой код:

```
def f(n):
    c=[]
    if n[0] > 0:
        c.append(b[0])
        k = 1
        for i in range(1, len(n)):
            if k == 1 and n[i] < 0:
                c.append(n[i])
                k = 0
            elif k == 0 and n[i] > 0:
                c.append(n[i])
                k = 1
    return len(c)

n=input()
a=list(map(int,input().split()))
b=[]
for i in range(len(a)-1):
   b.append(a[i+1]-a[i])
print(f(b)+1)
```

Comment: ну расскажите для начала как вы вообще собирались ее решать

Comment: Ну она вроде решается у меня, то есть ответы правильные выдает, а она у меня по времени не проходит
логика вроде у меня простая:
1.я делаю массив с разностями
2.в функции считаю все, то есть беру переменную K, если она равна одному значит нам нужен отрицательный элемент в массиве, если K==0, то нужен положительный элемент, так вроде все нормально заполняется

Comment: ну почти близко  в вашей задаче рассмотрен частный случай, когда первая разность больше 0, а она может быть и меньше 0

Comment: да точно, спасибо, а что мне со скоростью делать, у меня она просто по времени не проходит в тестах

Comment: а вы задайте себе вопрос - ЧТО ОТ МЕНЯ ТРЕБУЕТСЯ и смотрите что вы делаете - в результате много лишних действий можно откинуть, возможно вы теряете время на сборке списка `c`, который там не нужен - вы же нигде его элементы не используете, а только считаете его размер, ну так сразу и считайте размер :) увеличивайте счетчик `size` какой-нибудь

Comment: Точно! Так и сделаю, спасибо!

Comment: у меня алгоритм (не считая получения данных и вывода результата) получился в 2 строчки, не знаю правда насколько он быстрый, но его можно чуть-чуть ускорить возможно

Comment: а можно посмотреть?))

Comment: `res = len(arr) - len([i for i in range(1, len(seq)) if seq[i - 1] * abs(seq[i]) == seq[i] * abs(seq[i - 1])])` но есть один тип данных на котором сбоит - так что надо алгоритм чуть подкрутить